# How to get the response data length in an Apache2 custom module?

Tags: c, unix, apache2, apache

For the first time I am writing an Apache module, I have just finished my hello world program.

I have to get the values of the:

- 1 request length (which i assume it would be length of URi, r->uri) correct me if am wrong
- 2 response length
- 3 request data
- 4 response data

And store it in a log file.

I have gone through all the basic structures server_rec, request_rec, connection and process, but I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

I know this is basic, but could not find any article which gives me the above results :(

Below is my [hello world sample](http://pashabd.blogspot.se/2011/04/apache-hello-world-module-in-ubuntu.html):

```
/* The simplest HelloWorld module */
#include <httpd.h>
#include <http_protocol.h>
#include <http_config.h>
static int helloworld_handler(request_rec *r)
{
if (!r->handler || strcmp(r->handler, "helloworld")) {
return DECLINED;
}
if (r->method_number != M_GET) {
return HTTP_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED;
}
ap_set_content_type(r, "text/html;charset=ascii");
ap_rputs("<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN\">\n",
r);
ap_rputs("<html><head><title>Apache HelloWorld "
"Module</title></head>", r);
ap_rputs("<body><h1>Hello World!</h1>", r);
ap_rputs("<p>This is the Apache HelloWorld module!</p>", r);
ap_rputs("</body></html>", r);
return OK;
}
static void helloworld_hooks(apr_pool_t *pool)
{
ap_hook_handler(helloworld_handler, NULL, NULL, APR_HOOK_MIDDLE);
}
module AP_MODULE_DECLARE_DATA helloworld_module = {
STANDARD20_MODULE_STUFF,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
helloworld_hooks
} ;
```

I am able to store the output in text file, but was unable to get the above mentioned fields.

Comment: if your code is less than 50 lines, you should edit your post to show what you have done so far. If more than that, put it on pastebin and add a link here. Good luck.

Comment: k , thanks for information, i will try to do that

Comment: I edited your question to include the code, and use proper formatting. I also fixed capitalization in a bunch of places. Please, in the future, try to do this when asking :)

Comment: I am also new to apache development, but as far as I see, you will need to write filter, instead of handler.

Comment: Did you find the solution?